# Угол и позиция мыши. Godot, GDScript

Tags: godot

Как получить угол от ноды до мыши и позицию мыши относительно ноды? GDScript

Answer (score 0):

первое. вероятно, поможет:

```
get_angle_to
```

второе.

```
get_local_mouse_position()
```